# trace method 'u' argument equivalent for trace_add?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6

Considering tkinter [variable class'](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) `trace()` method is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html) since Python 3.6, new `trace_add()` method should be used:

- `trace('w', method)` has become `trace_add('write', method)`
- `trace('r', method)` has become `trace_add('read', method)`

I'm wondering how is the `'u'` argument now specified? 
For instance, consider the former:

`trace('wu', method)`

I can't find anything in the docs or anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, in such cases you can always fire up your REPL and call `help` on `trace_add` to examine its docstring.

```
>>> from tkinter import StringVar
>>> help(StringVar.trace_add)
```

For `trace_add` the following is stated:

> `trace_add(self, mode, callback)`
>
> Define a trace callback for the variable.
>
> *Mode is one of "read", "write", "unset", or a list or tuple of
>      such strings.*
>      Callback must be a function which is called when the variable is
>      read, written or unset.
>
> Return the name of the callback.

So, judging from that, `'wu'` should now be `['write', 'unset']`.